# implication versus conjunction correctness in FOL?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I've just started learning FOL and I'm really confused about whether to use conjunction or implications. For example, if I want to represent

```
some students who answer the easiest question do not answer the most difficult
```

I came up with several solutions that seem equivalent to me.

1) ∃x. (student(x) Λ solve(x, easy) Λ ¬solve(x, hard))

2) ∃x. (student(x) -> (solve(x, easy) Λ ¬solve(x, hard)))

3) ∃x. ((student(x) Λ solve(x, easy)) -> ¬solve(x, hard)))

Can anyone explain which is correct and why the others are wrong?

Comment: The phrase "some students" implies at least two students.  So, you probably need something like "there exists x, there exists y...".

Comment: It almost always helps to draw a pciture.  In this case a Venn diagram.  If you were to do so, you would discover that your third sentence claims that for *anything* that solved the hard problem, that thing is either not a student or did not solve the easy problem.  This seems a much wider claim than can be justified by the given sentence.  Also, "solve" $\neq$ "answer".

Comment: Try drawing the truth tables for your three statements. Two statements are equivalent exactly when they have the same truth tables.

Comment: @Eric So I guess 1) is incorrect as well because "anything can be x"?

Comment: @JessicaB they have different truth tables, but the issue is figuring out which one represents the proposition

Comment: @rola:  No.  In 1, you always have the constraint "student(x)".  Also, if you won't draw the picture, follow Jessica B's advice and construct the three truth tables.  Do not think you can make this all work without checking details as side work.

Comment: oh sure. no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the structure on which you evaluate your formulae. For simplicity I would introduce $3$ predicates $\mathsf{student}, \mathsf{solve\_easy}, \mathsf{solve\_hard}$. (The parameterized solve works but I think it is a little confusing)

If the universe of your structures contains both students and non-students (which I assume because you introduced the predicate $\mathsf{student}$) then:

- Formulae $1$ is correct. It states the existence of a student who answers easy questions but not difficult ones.
- Formulae $2$ is not correct. Assume that students solve no questions at all and there is at least one non-student. By the definition of implication the non-student satisfies $\mathsf{student}(x) \rightarrow \varphi(x)$ for **any** $\varphi$. Hence, the formulae is satisfied but it shouldn't be.
- Formulae $3$ is not correct. Assume again that students do not solve any questions and that there is a non-student.

If all elements in the universe are students all $3$ formulae are correct.

Comment: thanks for the conciseness!

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at it is to translate the logical statements into more everyday language, and see what they actually say.

1) There exists someone who is a student, answered the easy question, and didn't answer the hard question.

2) There exist someone who, if they are a student, answered the easy question and not the hard one (but if they're not a student we know nothing about what questions they answered).

3) There exists someone who, if they are both a student and answered the easy question, did not answer the hard question (if they are not a student, we do not know which questions they answered; if they are a student but did not answer the easy question we do not know if they answered the hard one).